# Alt+O Accelerator for OK Button on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have switched from Windows XP to Windows 7. In the dialog boxes in one program, the OK button on Windows XP used to have an "Alt+O" accelerator with it. In Windows 7, this key combination no longer presses the OK button.

Are there any settings in Windows 7 that I can change to get the XP behavior back?

The program in question is TortiseSVN. The commit dialog box in particular is where I want this. The default "enter presses OK" behavior doesn't work, because enter also enters a newline in the text box in the dialog. In XP, it was easy to type my entry and press alt+o to commit the changes. Now I have to type my entry, press tab a couple times, and press enter.

This is what I see in XP:

[image]

This is what I see in 7:

[image]

In general, alt+ works in Windows 7. But for this dialog box, for some reason, Windows 7 has chosen to turn off all the accelerators.

Comment: Does "Alt+<Key>" (where <Key> is another letter such as F) work on other applications e.g. Notepad?

Comment: Yes, in general alt+ works in Windows 7. But for this dialog box, for some reason, Windows 7 has chosen to turn off all the accelerators.

Comment: If you notice there's no underlines under any of the options (the R of Recent messages) on the dialog. Does Alt+ work at all in SVN?

Comment: On some of the dialogs, yes, the underlines and alt+ works. But for some dialogs (such as this one), they are turned off in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Ctrl + Enter?

Since it's not listed on [Window's own page on keyboard shortcuts:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Keyboard-shortcuts)

- Ctrl + Tab: Move forward through tabs
- Ctrl + Shift + Tab: Move back through tabs
- Tab: Move forward through options
- Shift + Tab: Move back through options
- **Alt + underlined letter: Perform the command (or select the option) that goes with that letter**
- Enter: Replaces clicking the mouse for many selected commands
- Spacebar: Select or clear the check box if the active option is a check box
- Arrow keys: Select a button if the active option is a group of option buttons
- F1: Display Help
- F4: Display the items in the active list
- Backspace: Open a folder one level up if a folder is selected in the Save As or Open dialog box

So if there's no underlined letter under the O, it's not within the standard controls of Windows 7

And after [some more Googling](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=windows+7++OK+dialog+box+shortcut+alt+%2B&btnG=Zoeken&meta=&aq=f&oq=), it seems that you're not the only one experiencing this problem

Comment: Ctrl+Enter works--I can retrain my fingers to do that.